# Set digit key listener on edit text android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have some multiple edittexts being created dynamically on which I need to set digits.

The user can enter numbers from 0-9
And '-' sign in the starting and not after any number.

Valid inputs

```
    a. 1235
    b. -568
```

Invalid inputs

```
    a. --1234
    b. 5-6
```

This is what I am using

```
      et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789-"));
```

How can I achieve my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
      et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true, false));
      //true stands for the signed number
      //false stands for decimal value
```